Error in x$slide : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors, when calling pipelined functions with passing arguments
I have this code for making a ppt from R:
library(officer)
library(tidyverse)

pres <- read_pptx("E:/Some folder/Document.pptx") 

title_slide_2 <- "Trial"
subtitle_slide_2 <- "Some subtitle"
paragraph_slide_2 <- "Something"

#function for making a placeholder
ph <- function(x,ph_value,ph_name){   
  ph_with(x,value = ph_value, location = ph_location_label(ph_label = ph_name))  
}
  
placeholder <- function(title = NULL,
                        subtitle = NULL,
                        table = NULL,
                        ul = NULL){
  
  if(!is.null(title)){  
    ph_title <- ph(title, "Title")
  }
  if(!is.null(subtitle)){  
    ph_subtitle <- ph(subtitle, "Subtitle")
  }  
  if(!is.null(table)){  
    ph_table <- ph(table, "Table")
  } 
  if(!is.null(ul)){  
    ph_ul <- ph(ul, "List")
  } 
  
  placeholders <- ph_title %>% 
                  ph_subtitle %>% 
                  ph_table %>%
                  ph_paragraph_1 %>%
                  ph_paragraph_2 %>%
                  ph_paragraph_3 %>%
                  ph_paragraph_4 %>%
                  ph_paragraph_5 %>%
                  ph_ul %>%
                  ph_picture_1 %>%
                  ph_picture_2 %>%
                  ph_abbreviations_1 %>%
                  ph_abbreviations_2 %>%
                  ph_headline_capture
    
    return(placeholders) 
}

my_pres <- pres %>%
  remove_slide(index = 1) %>%    
  add_slide(layout = "Slide 2", master = "Office Theme") %>%                                     
  placeholder(title = title_slide_2, subtitle_1 = subtitle_slide_2, paragraph_1 = paragraph_slide_2)
 
print(my_pres, glue::glue("Doc trial.pptx"))   
  


and it shows me an error stating: Error in x$slide : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to change this code? I don't know whether it is ok to make a function for placeholders this way, and whether I made a proper calling of that function, along with passing the arguments

There are several issues with your code. After some refactoring here is a working minimal reproducible example using the default pptx template shipped with officer:
library(officer)

pres <- read_pptx()

title_slide_2 <- "Trial"
subtitle_slide_2 <- "Some subtitle"

ph <- function(x, ph_value, ph_name) {
  ph_with(x, value = ph_value, location = ph_location_label(ph_label = ph_name))
}

placeholder <- function(x,
                        title = NULL,
                        subtitle = NULL,
                        table = NULL,
                        ul = NULL) {
  ph_title <- \(x)  if (!is.null(title)) ph(x, title, "Title 1") else x
  
  ph_subtitle <- \(x)  if (!is.null(subtitle)) ph(x, subtitle, "Content Placeholder 2") else x
  
  ph_table <- \(x)  if (!is.null(table)) ph(x, table, "Content Placeholder 3") else x

  x |> 
    ph_title() |> 
    ph_subtitle() |> 
    ph_table()
}

my_pres <- pres |> 
  #remove_slide(index = 1) %>%
  add_slide(layout = "Two Content", master = "Office Theme") |>
  placeholder(
    title = title_slide_2, 
    subtitle = subtitle_slide_2
  )

print(my_pres, "Doc trial.pptx")



Thank you very much @stefan. However, when I try to implement your answer to my situation of already having a template, thus the need to leave 'remove_slide(index = 1)' in order to remove the first slide, it shows me an error: Error in fortify_location.location_label(location, doc = x) :
no selected row.  Do you possibly know what could be the reason for that. I wrote this:
my_pres <- pres |>
remove_slide(index = 1) |>
add_slide(layout = "Slajd 4a", master = "Office Theme") |>
placeholder(
title = title_slide_2,
subtitle_1 = subtitle_slide_2
)

This is what I wrote:  placeholder <- function(x, title = NULL, subtitle_1 = NULL){ ph_title <- (x)  if (!is.null(title)) ph(x, title, "Naslov") else x
ph_subtitle_1 <- (x)  if (!is.null(subtitle_1)) ph(x, subtitle_1, "Podnaslov 1") else x
x |>
ph_title() |>
ph_subtitle_1()    }
my_pres <- pres |>
remove_slide(index = 1) |>
add_slide(layout = "Slajd 4a", master = "Office Theme") |>
placeholder(
title = title_slajd_2,
subtitle_1 = subtitle_slajd_2
)

From the error I would guess (that this an issue with an incorrect placeholder name, e.g. you can reproduce the error using the default template when you use e.g. ph(x, title, "FOO"), i.e. in that case you get the mentioned error as there is no ph named "FOO".

Thank you so much!!! Yes, I named the placeholder for the subtitle differently in the ppt slide master and in the code. Now I've changed that and it's working! Thank you again!! Can you tell me one more thing, please? What does  \(x) mean in ph_title <- \(x)  if (!is.null(title)) ph(x, title, "Title 1") else x?

\(x) is just a shorthand notation for function(x), i.e. you can do ph_title <- function(x) if (!is.null(title)) ph(x, title, "Title 1") else x.
